# ggplot2: grouping fails when plotting multiple values

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, bar-chart

I am trying to plot a bar plot with `ggplot2`, with grouped values.
I can do it plotting one variable, but when I try to super impose a second one the grouping fails.
How should I fix it?

As a guideline, the final graph should three region with three sector each. Each of these should have a darker part to indicate the share of projects announced but not financed.

Thanks in advance.

```
    set.seed(0)
    db <- data.frame(
      project_region = rep(c("a","b","c"),3),
      project_sector = c(rep("s_1",3),rep("s_2",3),rep("s_3",3)),
      announced = sample(1:100, 9),
      financed = runif(9, 0, 1))
    db$financed = round(db$announced*db$financed,0) 
    
    ggplot(db, mapping = aes(x = reorder(project_region, announced), announced, fill=project_sector)) + 
      geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
      coord_flip()
    
    #FAIL

    ggplot(NULL, mapping = aes(x = reorder(project_region, announced),announced,fill=project_sector)) + 
          geom_bar(aes(fill = "announced"), data = db, alpha = 0.5, position="dodge", stat="identity") +
          geom_bar(aes(fill = "financed"), data = db, alpha = 0.5, position="dodge", stat="identity")  +
          coord_flip()

#FAIL
db1 <- db
db2 <- db[c("project_region","project_sector","financed")] %>% rename(announced=financed)

ggplot(NULL, aes(project_region, announced)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = "announced"), data = db1, alpha = 0.5, position="dodge") +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = "financed"), data = db2, alpha = 0.5, position="dodge")  +
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: as a starter: `ggplot(NULL, mapping = aes(x = reorder(project_region, announced),fill=project_sector)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = announced), data = db, alpha = 0.5, position="dodge", stat="identity") +
  geom_bar(aes(y = financed), data = db, alpha = 1, position="dodge", stat="identity")  +
  coord_flip()`

Comment: identical but shorter re-write of my above comment: `ggplot(db , mapping = aes(x = reorder(project_region, announced), fill = project_sector)) + 
  geom_col(aes(y = announced), alpha = 0.5, position="dodge") +
  geom_col(aes(y = financed), position="dodge")  +
  coord_flip()`

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can `pivot_longer` the `announced` and `financed` columns, and then plot with `project_region` as a facet.

```r
library(tidyverse)

db %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(announced, financed)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(project_sector, value, group = name, fill = name)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun = mean, position = position_dodge(.9)) +
  facet_wrap(~project_region, labeller = label_both)
```

[image]